# Datagridview: how to commit checkbox and and immediately filter by it?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview DataGridView1, bound to a DataTable1BindingSource, with the only writable cell being a checkbox bound to the boolean column "IsSelected". As soon as the user checks the checkbox, I want to show only the row where the checkbox is checked. So i put the following code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    DataTable1BindingSource.Filter = "IsSelected"
End Sub
```

But it does not work - once the ckeckbox is checked, the datagridview does not show any rows at all.

If I move the statement DataTable1BindingSource.Filter = "IsSelected" to a separate command button,

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataTable1BindingSource.Filter = "IsSelected"
End Sub
```

then upon editing the checkbox and then clicking the button, it works as expected, i.e. shows only this row.

Why it does not work when it's issued immediately?

Comment: I wonder, if it has to do something with the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged. Have you tried i.e. CellMouseUp event?

Comment: MouseUp probably would be quite a desperate workaround, some users, theoretically, may operate by keyboard... but even that does not work. EditedFormattedValue changes, but then EndEdit does not push it to the bindingsource.

Comment: OK, I read it again and I see the event is issue (rows are gone). Must be the filter condition then I think...  Did you try .Filter = "IsSelected = 1" ? If this doesn't work, can you test how many rows in DataSource has IsSelected = 1?

Comment: The same filter, from a separate button, works perfectly, as long as there's no attempt to filter "on the fly". 


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.DataTable1BindingSource.Filter = "thevalue=9"
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    sender.endedit

    Me.DataTable1BindingSource.Filter = "thevalue=9" ' <--- comment out this line, and Button1_click will work
    End Sub

Comment: (sorry, couldn't figure out the way for the code to look right in the prev. comment)

Comment: issue was a type error, I meant issued. Could you try, within your DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged (without the Button1) count your IsSelected rows? Just count it in a variable and insert a breakpoint, or insert after your filter this code:         Dim N As Int16
        For ir = 0 To Me.DatagridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim dr As DataGridViewRow = Me.DatagridView1.Rows(ir)
            If dr.Cells("IsSelected").Value Then
                N += 1
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox("N=" & N)

Comment: Found the reason. After 
sender.endedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason. After

```
Sender.EndEdit
```

, before applying the filter, have to also issue

```
DataTable1BindingSource.EndEdit
```

Then it all works as expected.